# Rounded Rectangle Out of Proportion when not at origin

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a small setup where you can type in rectangle dimensions to draw a rounded rectangle. However, if I put the x and y coordinates to 0,0 the rectangle comes out fine. I put in 200,200 for width and height and can tell its exactly 1/4 of the canvas.

However, if put in 1,1 or other coordinates, the rectangle becomes way too large. I put in 200, 200 again, expecting to only be shifted, but its so big its off the canvas. What is going on?

JS

```
function myfunction(){

    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var w = document.getElementById("boxwidth").value;
    var h = document.getElementById("boxheight").value;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,400,400);
    //roundRect(ctx,0,0,w,h,1);
    roundRect(ctx,1,1,w,h,1);
}

function roundRect(ctx, x, y, width, height, radius, fill, stroke) {

  if (typeof stroke == "undefined" ) {
    stroke = true;
  }
  if (typeof radius === "undefined") {
    radius = 5;
  }
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + radius, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius, y + height);
  ctx.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y + radius);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
  ctx.closePath();
  if (stroke) {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  if (fill) {
    ctx.fill();
  }        
}
```

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aymbyo3y/8/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem in this two lines

```
var w = document.getElementById("boxwidth").value;
var h = document.getElementById("boxheight").value;
```

this lines return *string*, but you need *int*, so you should use *parseInt* like

```
var w = parseInt(document.getElementById("boxwidth").value, 10);
var h = parseInt(document.getElementById("boxheight").value, 10);
```

If you not convert string to int your calculation for coordinates is wrong:
for example `w='100'; h='100';x=1;y=1;radius=1`

```
ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);

ctx.lineTo(1 + '100' - 1, 1);
```

so get: 1 + '100' - 1 = (1 + '100') - 1 = '1100' - 1 = 1099

but you expect: 1 + 100 - 1 = (1 + 100) - 1 = 101 - 1 = 100

If you look to snippet below you can see that with using *parseInt* all work correct.

```js
    function myfunction() {

      var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var w = parseInt(document.getElementById("boxwidth").value, 10);
      var h = parseInt(document.getElementById("boxheight").value, 10);
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
      //roundRect(ctx,0,0,w,h,1);
      roundRect(ctx, 50, 50, w, h, 1);
    }

    function roundRect(ctx, x, y, width, height, radius, fill, stroke) {

      if (typeof stroke == "undefined") {
        stroke = true;
      }
      if (typeof radius === "undefined") {
        radius = 5;
      }
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x + radius, y);
      ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
      ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius, y + height);
      ctx.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);
      ctx.lineTo(x, y + radius);
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
      ctx.closePath();
      if (stroke) {
        ctx.stroke();
      }
      if (fill) {
        ctx.fill();
      }
    }

    myfunction();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
X:
<input type="number" value="200" id="boxwidth" onchange="myfunction()" />Y:
<input type="number" value="200" id="boxheight" onchange="myfunction()" />
```